# Multiple communication listeners in a Service Fabric service

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, zeromq, azure-service-fabric

Is it possible to have multiple communication listeners within a single stateless service, for example a self-hosted Web API and also a service bus using something like ZeroMQ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not at the moment. However, this will be possible in the public preview release coming next month (November 2015).

Comment: I created service fabric to connect with third party apis. I need to use two third party api(contis,Yodlee). Whether can i create two Stateless WebAPi for each one.